# libGDX zoom implementation isn't working right

Tags: libgdx

I would like to achieve a zoom effect that is similar to "Clash of Clans". I'm currently implementing zoom in a way that pretty much all the tutorials online do. There are of course a my camera specific constants to make it zoom at good speeds for my camera.The code DOES WORK.

```
@Override
public boolean zoom(float initialDistance, float distance) {
    float zoomAmount = -1*(distance - initialDistance)/10000;
    cameraHelper.addZoom(zoomAmount);   
    return true;
}
```

The camera helper class does this simple stuff:

```
public void addZoom(float amount) {
    setZoom(zoom + amount);
}
public void apply(OrthographicCamera camera) {
    camera.zoom = zoom;
    camera.update();
}
```

So this does work. When I fling two fingers in one continuous motion and then stop moving the fingers on the screen, let's say I zoom in with zoomAmount = x, zoom gets called once and the zoom is done.

Problem: 
However, if I then wiggle one, or both, of the fingers just a tiny bit, zoom gets called again with that same value for zoomAmount = x. So by wiggling a finger, it will simply keep adding to zoom and keep zooming in or out (depending on the current state of zoomAmount).

Question:
How do I make libgdx or java remember my original camera.zoom much like initialDistance in the zoom() method. OR, is there any other trick that I can do to have a responsive and smooth zoom (without removing fingers from the screen) much like the game "Clash of Clans".

Extra info:

I have tried pinch, same effect. I have thought about having a base zoom value and then some kind of percentage multiplier, however because I have to update the camera by setting its zoom (camera.zoom = zoom;) I can't think of a clever trick with adding or subtracting any values that will not be effected by zoom() being constantly called. Any thoughts anyone?

Comment: you didn't exactly state a question.. Or maybe it isn't clear to me

Comment: Sorry about that, I clarified it a bit, hope it helps :)

Comment: just store it as a camera.zoom as some variable... am i not understanding this?

Comment: Solves it, thanks you kind of led me to it. The problem was that I wanted a variable that's like initialDistance variable in the zoom method. libGDX passes the exact same value to initialDistance for the duration of the zoom (two fingers on screen). So I simply made a variable that changes only when initialDistance changes. Thanks :)

Comment: @Artash, how you did that, could you set the code plz, thank you